# sharepoint 2010, windows 7 i cant upload multiple file

Tags: 2010, file-upload, windows

I am having problems with sharepoint 2010 and windows 7 as I cant upload multiple file. 
i am listed as a site owner, i am using office 2010 both 32 bit and 64 bit.

But i have the upload multiple documents greyed out. What have a screwed up ? Can anyone help ?

Answer (score 6):

Uploading Documents requires Active X Control so I would recommend you to use Internet Explorer with Active X control installed.

The Active X control used for the multi document upload does not exist in a 64-bit version.
The 64-bit Office version also does not include the 32-bit version of the active x controls.
That's why it is recommend to use the 32-bit version of Office in combination with SharePoint.

or if you can use sharepoint workspace then follow these steps

> Upload files to SharePoint Workspace, and sync it to site.
>
> a. Log on to SharePoint Team site, then click "Site Actions" -> "Sync to SharePoint Workspace". The content in site will be synced to
>   Workspace.
>
> b. Choose the folder which one you want to be uploaded document, then
>   click "Add document" to upload the .wav file.
>
> c. Click the option "Sync"->"Sync Workspace" in the top ribbon, all
>   changed in Workspace will be synced to SharePoint site.
>
> Open files in explorer, and then copy the .wav file to it. Click
>   Library Tools->Library, choose the option "Open with Explorer".

Check this link out, guy has same problem as you

[Problem uploading documents](http://community.office365.com/en-us/forums/154/t/11007.aspx)

Hope this helped :)

Comment: The good news is SharePoint 2013 has built-in support, and can work with multiple browsers. http://www.iotap.com/Blog/tabid/673/entryid/247/Drag-and-Drop-feature-added-to-SharePoint-2013.aspx.